# Simple ways to transform form's data into JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to transform values from form's fields into JSON object, but I want it to be in a specific format. Something like this:

```
{name: "John", surname: "Smith"}
```

Is there an easy way to do it? I don't want to build each field manually since there might be a lot of them, and I don't want to do it this way

```
var data = JSON.stringify($("#newUserForm").serializeArray());
```

because in this case, JSON will look something like this:

```
[{"name":"name","value":"John"},{"name":"surname","value":"Smith"}]
```

Maybe there are some jQuery plugins or other tricks to do it in one line of code?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(formdata, ([name, value]) => ({[name]: value}))));`

Comment: that serialization format won't allow repeating param names, which the URL format supports. you can accum the serializedArray if you want a more compact representation and don't mind dropping repeats.